# Set a new AccountExpirationDate for existing account in AD with C#

Tags: c#, active-directory

I am searching for a solution to extend the AuthenticablePrincipal.**AccountExpirationDate** Property of an existing AD account with c# code.

With the following code i am able to retrieve the expiration date of an existing AD account, but i am not able to set a new date.

```
PrincipalContext principalContext = GetPrincipalContext();

UserPrincipal userPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(principalContext, IdentityType.SamAccountName, userName);

if (userPrincipal.AccountExpirationDate.HasValue)
{
  expiration = userPrincipal.AccountExpirationDate.Value;
}

userPrincipal.AccountExpirationDate = new DateTime(2019,9,20);
```

The expiration date in AD of the account is not changing.
Do you have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're just missing the most important line :)

```
userPrincipal.Save();
```

Without that, your changes won't be saved.